# CloudDeploy fails when using WolframAlpha as APIFunction

Tags: wolfram-cloud, wolfram-alpha-queries, cloud-deploy

I am trying to create a Wolfram API that returns, for an input expression, how Wolfram Alpha interprets that input.

For example, given the string "1 plus 2", the API should return "1 + 2".

Locally, the following definition works.

```
api = APIFunction[{"expr" -> "String"}, First[WolframAlpha[#expr, "WolframForms"]] &]
```

However, when deploying it, using `CloudDeploy[api]`, the result returned is always `First[$Failure]`.

Why does the `WolframAlpha` function work locally, but not when used in `CloudDeploy`?

Comment: My guess it is a limitation of a license plan you have for Mathematica Online. You can ask Wolfram Support.

Comment: @Kuba I see. Thanks!

Comment: Otoh every plan has WA calls included :/ http://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/pricing/ you never know. There's a lot of confusion about what is possible, where and for how much.

Comment: I have a license for Wolfram|One and this doesn't work. My impression is that `WolframAlpha` intentionally does not work in `CloudDeploy` under these circumstances.

Comment: Same issue appears when you do `CloudEvaluate[WolframAlpha["1+1"]]`, for instance.