# Querying WolframAlpha from WolframScript

Tags: scripting, wolfram-alpha-queries

Is it possible to query WolframAlpha from a wolframscript query? The following yields `$Failed`:

```
wolframscript -cloud -code "WolframAlpha[\"capital of Egypt\"]"
$Failed
```

Comment: It seems this only doesn't work when using the `-cloud` option. This is consistent with `CloudEvaluate[WolframAlpha["capital of egypt"]]` also returning `$Failed`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185029/clouddeploy-fails-when-using-wolframalpha-as-apifunction